# PHP preg_replace doesn't replace html's tag content

Tags: php, html, regex, svg, preg-replace

I'm trying to remove all SVG tag inners with preg_replace but it doesn't work no matter how I try.

I'm trying something like this:

```
$tmp=preg_replace("/(?<=<svg )(.*)(?=\\\/svg>)/", "", $tmp);
```

where $tmp is:

```
"svg":"<svg xmlns="http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2000\/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="269" height="264" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns:xlink="http:\/\/www.w3.org\/1999\/xlink"><g><image x="0" y="0" width="269" height="264" preserveAspectRatio="none" ><\/image><\/g><\/svg>"
```

Expexted result:

```
"svg": "<svg \/svg>"
```

Or something like this. I need it for the next json_decode.

But the result i see is:

1) Nothing is done

2) Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'v'

However it works in online editors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may need to start/end with a different character rather than `/`, try `%`

Comment: @Scuzzy result the same for `$tmp=preg_replace("%(?<=<svg )(.*)(?=\\\/svg>)%", "", $tmp);` (nothing replaced)

Comment: I tired your code and it worked. `"svg":"<svg \/svg>"`

Comment: Ok maybe it's my fault, i posted here just part of data, but it should work fine for any string length... my is just to big to post it here, it has Base64 image.

Comment: Just use `"/<svg\s+\K.*?(?=\\\\\/svg>)/s"`.

Comment: Ultimatly what are you hoping to achive by editing this SVG document? Like I can kinda see what you are trying to do with the code but I'm not sure the why.

Comment: It's best not to use regexp to process HTML, use `DOMDocument`.

Comment: @Scuzzy i want json_decode, but there is " qoute chars in svg tag and i have no idea how to handle it, in my DB it stored like this `"svg":"&lt;svg xmlns=&quot;http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2000\/svg&quot;` but once i use it in php script it replaces on " and ruine everything.

Comment: Yeah if that's json malformed with quote tags then something's not right with the soruce of the data. Are you trying to output a json object in a html page for consumption client side by any chance?

Comment: Where did the xml for the svg originate from? I'd focus on getting it into the database in the correct format.